# Find cause of allocations in JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Recently I run into a problem with memory allocation in JVM.

According to GC log and jvisulvm my application is creating a ton int arrays.

```
...
15.587: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387648K->192K(8388096K)] 8413385K->25945K(16776704K), 0.0004254 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.592: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387776K->192K(8388096K)] 8413529K->26001K(16776704K), 0.0003679 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.596: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387776K->96K(8388096K)] 8413585K->25929K(16776704K), 0.0004090 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.602: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387680K->128K(8388096K)] 8413513K->25993K(16776704K), 0.0004101 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.606: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387712K->128K(8388096K)] 8413577K->26025K(16776704K), 0.0003756 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.611: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387712K->160K(8388096K)] 8413609K->26097K(16776704K), 0.0003965 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
15.626: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8387744K->128K(8388096K)] 8413681K->26105K(16776704K), 0.0004195 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
...
```

[image]

I searched the whole codebase for "new int[]" and found only two allocations of which I am pretty sure they are run just once. That leads me to belief that the arrays are allocated either in some library or in JRE.

How can I find root of these allocations?

Comment: If your profiler doesn't give you the code paths for where leaks/allocations are occurring, get a new profiler. Always a step one. With that first line, it should be able to tell you all the code paths that allocate `int` arrays.

Comment: @Qix I am able to get a heap dump, but for some reason it's only 7MB big. I believe the profiler is running GC before taking a dump and thus destroying the int arrays.

Comment: That doesn't matter, getting the code paths (stack traces) for where these int arrays are being allocated is crucial. I would be surprised if VisualVM doesn't do that for you. A heap dump isn't going to help you much in this case; this is a clear memory leak.

Comment: @Qix It's only a memory *leak* if the code is done with the `int[]`. If the code is still using it, it's not a *leak*, but simply a need for more memory than available, in which case adding memory or changing algorithm is the answer, not searching for leaks.

Comment: @Andreas If you're seeing strange memory usage patterns that you aren't expecting from your code (as OP has specified), always investigate it as a leak until proven otherwise. Pretty good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Qix Since memory leaks are notoriously difficult to find, I'd *start* by looking at what the app is doing at the time. If that doesn't pan out, I'd look for leaks *second*. Jumping straight to memory leak, without considering the other, is just .... well, sub-optimal. E.g. the app could simply be processing an extraordinarily large file. Much easier to detect than finding cause of memory leak.

Comment: I suggest you use flight recorder in Java 7/8 or a commercial profiler such as YoutKit as these will give you the full stack.  Most likely these are being created by your matrix library